Magento 2 : Block Threw an Exception after upgrade to 2.4.7
Got error
"The "sales_invoice_view" block threw an exception, and it can't be rendered."
Not just sales_invoice_view alot of admin areas when opening says this error.
like another one
The "adminhtml.cache.container" block threw an exception, and it can't be rendered. in vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/ExceptionHandlerBlock.php:59

Seems unclear as to what is the issue. But since the word cache is mentioned and since you are looking for a place to start, I'd clear cache: bearing in mind, cache can be persistent. So, the idea is to restart the redis service if you use redis or clear the var/cache, var/page_cache folder otherwise.
Other than this, you need to check the logs: both Magento and server.
Clearing the generated folder will not hurt either.
Although you may think there is only one issue because there is only one change (the upgrade to 2.4.7), the 2 issues you have spotted can be entirely different.
In practice, assuming your Magento system is local, I'd set it in developer mode and then I'd verify Magento's health, I tend to run php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Finally, if the setup:upgrade command fails,
php bin/magento modules:status gives good result to show the place that is faulty

The issue seems to be when updated PHP version to 8.2
When move back to the previous magento version i still have same issue and then after changing back php version to 8.1 everything works fine.
